# IllegalArgumentException in DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java

This is my Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-09-16" is malformed at "-09-16"
   at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
   at Project.BorrowedModel.getDateDifference(BorrowedModel.java:216)
   at Project.BorrowedModel.UserHasLatedReturn(BorrowedModel.java:195)
   ...
```

And this is my methods:

(This code is for detecting if a user in our library has a book that not returned yet in 10 days).

```
public boolean UserHasLatedReturn(int userID) throws NullPointerException {
    String todayDate = getTodayDate();
    String userBorrowDate = getUserBorrowDate(userID);
    if (userBorrowDate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int difference = getDateDifference(userBorrowDate, todayDate);
    if (difference > 10) { // More that 10 days
        System.out.println("You have " + difference + " Days Delay in returning your previouse book");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public int getDateDifference(String firstDate, String secondDate) {

    DateTime d1, d2, dt1 = null, dt2 = null;
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY/MM/dd");

    try {
        d1 = format.parseDateTime(firstDate);  // Exception is here
        d2 = format.parseDateTime(secondDate);

        dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
        dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays();
}

public String getTodayDate() {
    Calendar todayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/dd");
    String strDate = simpleFormat.format(todayDate.getTime());
    return strDate;
}

public String getUserBorrowDate(int userID) {
    String query = "SELECT Borrow_Date FROM Borrowed WHERE User_ID=?";
    String date = null;
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);) {
        ps.setInt(1, userID);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            date = rs.getString("Borrow_Date");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

This code works correct before, But not doesn't work!

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: So, you're looking for a format like YYYY/MM/dd, giving it a format like YYYY-MM-dd, and it doesn't like it... What was the question, again?

Comment: @DavidConrad Where of code give me a format like `YYYY-MM-dd`?

Comment: Read the error you posted, look at what it is saying the invalid format is.  You need to either change the pattern you are trying to parse with, or change the string you're passing in.

Comment: @user3808021 I suggest that you step through your code and look at the values of the variables. In particular, pay attention to the Strings that you pass to the `getDateDifference()` method.

Comment: You are getting the wrongly formatted date from `getUserBorrowDate()`.  Look there and post the code for that method if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are getting a date string in the wrong format from `getUserBorrowDate()` and passing it eventually to `getDateDifference()` which throws the Exception.  Rather than doing all that string parsing, I'd just use `ResultSet.getDate()` and compare dates.

```
public boolean UserHasLatedReturn(int userID) throws NullPointerException {
    LocalDate todayDate = new LocalDate();
    LocalDate userBorrowDate = getUserBorrowDate(userID);
    if (userBorrowDate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    int difference = Days.daysBetween(userBorrowDate, todayDate).getDays();
    if (difference > 10) { // More than 10 days
        System.out.println("You have " + difference + " Days Delay in returning your previous book");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public LocalDate getUserBorrowDate(int userID) {
    String query = "SELECT Borrow_Date FROM Borrowed WHERE User_ID=?";
    LocalDate date = null;
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "root", "2323");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);) {
        ps.setInt(1, userID);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            date = LocalDate.fromDateFields(rs.getDate("Borrow_Date"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The database returns dates in the `YYYY-MM-dd` format. You need to write your Java code to be consistent with this format.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is `"YYYY/MM/dd"` but you give a `"YYYY-MM-dd"`

Change to format to `"YYYY-MM-dd"`

Comment: Should i change `YYYY/MM/dd` to `YYYY-MM-dd` in `getTodayDate()` or in `getDateDifference(...)` ?

Comment: Well according to your stack trace, the exception is in getDateDifference
But I would change it in both methods.

Comment: @user3808021 probably both...you should also take a close look at `getUserBorrowDate()`